# Invalid variance with delegate in interface method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Why does the following interface declaration produce an invalid variance error?

```
public interface ICache<in TKey, TValue>
{
  TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory);
}
```

The compiler says:

> Error CS1961  Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TKey' must be covariantly valid on 'ICache<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey, Func<TKey, TValue>)'. 'TKey' is contravariant.

The problem lies with the use of `TKey` in the `Func` parameter. But `TKey` is being used as an input as `Func` requires. Why must it be covariant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: The C# compiler is keeping you safe.

Effectively, "nested input in an input position makes an output" when it comes to generic variance. Your method has a parameter which *itself* accepts a `TKey`, which sort of reverses the variance.

It's easiest to see why it's prohibited by imagining if it were allowed. Then you could write:

```
public class ObjectKeyedCache : ICache<object, object>
{
    public object GetOrAdd(object key, Func<object, object> valueFactory)
    {
        // Let's ignore the specified key, and just pass in an object!
        return valueFactory(new object());
    }
}
```

Then you could write:

```
ICache<object, object> objectKeyedCache = new ObjectKeyedCache();
// Ah, due to contravariance, this should be okay...
ICache<string, object> stringKeyedCache = objectKeyedCache;

// Okay, this is a weird cache function, but bear with me
stringKeyedCache("key", text => text.Length);
```

That would then try to pass an `object` reference into the `Func<string, object>` created from the lambda expression `text => text.Length`. Bang!

For even more details, read [Part 5 of Eric Lippert's variance blog series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/24/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-five-higher-order-functions-hurt-my-brain/). This is the most important part of that post:

> Doing so makes my brain hurt, but this also builds character, so here we go!

Anything that makes *Eric's* brain hurt should probably be considered a major health hazard for the rest of it. You have been warned.

Comment: This was one of the reasons why we pushed back a little bit on "in" and "out" as the keywords to indicate variance. The fact that sometimes things that go "in" are actually not valid in a contravariant context is confusing. But the other choices, like using "+" and "-" as some languages do, seemed to be even more confusing.